# Не могу внести данные в БД из чекбокса

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть форма из которой берутся данные в бд, работают все строки формы кроме этого чекбокса(html код):

```html
              <label class="description" for="element_3">Чем нарисована </label>
                <input type="hidden" name="element_3[]" value='Весь массив' />
                масло
                <input type="checkbox" name='element_3[1]' value="Масло" />
                акварель
                <input type="checkbox" name='element_3[2]' value="Акварель" />
                карандаш
                <input type="checkbox" name='element_3[3]' value="Карандаш" />
```

Так выглядит мой запрос на php:

```
$elem = $_POST['element_3'];
extract($elem, EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID, "wddx");
$maslo = $wddx_1 ;
print_r($maslo) ;
$test1 = 1234;
mysqli_query( $connectdb , 'INSERT INTO `cms_arts`(`name`, `time`, `what_used`, 
`author`) VALUES ( ' .$_POST['element_1']. ',' .$_POST['element_2']. ','. $maslo 
.',' .$_POST['element_4_1']. $_POST['element_4_2']. ')');
```

Если в sql запрос вставить вместо $maslo переменную $test1, то все работает. В чем проблема? как внести выбранные пункты из чекбокса в базу данных?

Comment: Вы в списке столбцов в запросе 4 перечислили, а в `VALUES` у вас 5. Такой запрос вообще работать не должен.

Comment: Что за `extract` вообще? У Вас `element_3` массив, вот и обрабатывайте его как массив

Comment: @DaemonHK пытался, но у меня как будто не видит этот массив в запросе, как конкретно его обработать, подскажите?

Comment: @сергейачадовский, попробуйте так для начала: `$elem = $_POST['element_3']; foreach($elem as $e){ var_dump($e); }`

Comment: И еще (пожелание): каждый чекбокс должен иметь свой label, чтобы я мог просто кликать по названию.

Comment: @DaemonHK пробовал так, всю информацию о любом элементе массива выводит. Именно не получается вывести их в бд. Лейблы у чекбоксов тоже были, просто код уже многое перетерпел. Мучаюсь долго над такой мелочью)

Comment: @сергейачадовский покажите именно что выводит

Comment: @DaemonHK вот фрагмент html кода с чекбоксом             `<label class="description" for="element_3">Чем нарисована </label>
                    <label  for="element_3[1]">Масло</label>
   <input  name="element_3[1]" type="checkbox" value="Масло" />
                    <label  for="element_3[2]">Акварель</label>
            <input  name="element_3[2]" type="checkbox" value="Акварель" />
                    <label  for="element_3[3]">Карандаш</label>
            <input  name="element_3[3]" type="checkbox" value="Карандаш" />`

Comment: @DaemonHK вот php запрос

Comment: $elem = $_POST['element_3'];
foreach($elem as $e){
 var_dump($e);
}

mysqli_query( $connectdb , 'INSERT INTO `cms_arts`(`name`, `time`, `what_used`, `author`) VALUES ( ' .$_POST['element_1']. ',' .$_POST['element_2']. ','. $e .',' .$_POST['element_4_1']. $_POST['element_4_2']. ')');

Comment: @DaemonHK в бд ничего не идет если вставить запрос в foreach. На странице выводятся выбранные пункты 

string(10) "Масло" string(16) "Акварель" string(16) "Карандаш"

Comment: @DaemonHK что мне изменить в запросе, чтоб он работал?

Comment: @сергейачадовский, вы же запрос не в цикле воспроизводите, а после него и почему вы остальные элементы вставляете снова как есть? Чтобы легче было разобраться: а) переименуйте ваши поля в более понятные значения, например `name`, `time` вместо абстрактных `element`, б) напишите мне в скайп (мой ник маленькими буквами) (если хотите), так быстрее будет просто.